# I'm unable to find the function or code that creates the Drupal Calendar navigation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

in the main tpl file I see print theme('date_navigation', $view) that displays the nav. I've went through all the tpl and includes to find where the code is processed but I cannot.

I want to make a custom navigation for my calendar and will need to override it or change it somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah the date.navigation.tpl.php is what outputs the nav for the calendar. It is located in the Date module theme folder.